# Can I find coordinates that meet with linear equation?

Tags: python, geometry, linear-equation

I have linear equation and list of coordinates.
Can I find coordinates that meet with linear equation?

[image]

Comment: I think you can check if your points satisfy the linear equation. those are your desired points.

Answer (score 1):

If the eqution is like this: y=ax+b (which is linear equation)
Then you basicly just enter the x value form your coordinate and see if the output y value is the same as the y value from your coordinate. A and B should be known since you have the equation already.